# Get rows from table ignoring results from subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `original_id` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `original_id` (`original_id`)
);


INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `title`, `original_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(14, 'A Title', NULL, 0),
(26, 'Another title', NULL, 0),
(27, 'A Third Title', NULL, 0),
(29, 'A Title', 14, 4),
(30, 'A Forth Title', NULL, 0),
(31, 'A Fifth Title', NULL, 0),
(32, 'A Third Title', 27, 4),
(33, 'A Sixth Title', NULL, 0),
(34, 'A Forth Title', 30, 6);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3857e/1

user_id=0 are the public records

user_id>0 are private records originated from a public record, where original_id refers to the original record

I need to get rows where a text search is satisfied, excluding third-party records (no problem until now), and the original rows from where my copies were made.

Is it possible to get it using only a select + subselect ?

Comment: What are your desired results with your sample data?  Not sure I completely understand your question.

Comment: Hi sgeddes, I need to make a search excluding third-party (user_id != me AND user_id>0) and excluding originals copied by me.

Comment: I don't understand that either. As sgeddes said: ´What result rows do you expect? user_id=0 means public. user_id>0 means private. Which user id means "me"? Which user_id means "third party"? Are you looking for a query with one user_id given? If so, what results would you expect for user_id 4, and what for user_id 6, and what for user_id 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where "me" is `4`:

```
SELECT b1.* FROM books b1
LEFT JOIN books b2
  ON b2.original_id = b1.id AND b2.user_id = 4
WHERE (b1.user_id = 0 AND b2.id IS NULL)
  OR b1.user_id = 4
```

`(b1.user_id = 0 AND b2.id IS NULL)` gets the public ones that I didn't copy.

`b1.user_id = 4` gets mine.

Answer (score 1):

Some modifications on following can help;

```
select * from books a
where a.original_id is null
and not exists (select 'a' from books b
where a.id = b.original_id)
```

Comment: It shold be like this: `SELECT * FROM books AS b WHERE title LIKE 'A%' AND (user_id=0 OR user_id=4) AND not exists (select id from books AS c where b.id = c.original_id)`, but it's not returning the line 30 (which were copied by the user 6)

Comment: You are welcome. I think it is consistent with your expectation 'exclude the original rows from where my copies were made'. Sorry for not getting expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not precisely clear on your needs, but would something like this work for you?

```
SELECT * 
FROM books AS b 
WHERE b.title LIKE '%mySearchStr%'
  AND b.user_id IN (0, myUserID)
  AND b.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT b2.original_id 
     FROM books AS b2 
     WHERE b2.user_id NOT IN (0, myUserID)
    )
;
```